# converting p ∧ (p→q) into conjunctive form

Tags: conjunctive-normal-form

I want to convert p ∧ (p→q) into conjunctive form.

I started like this:

```
P ∧ (¬p ∨ q)
```

But I'm not sure how to continue and how to change this formula to conjunctive normal form.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Then use [distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)) and [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%20and%20implies(p,q))

$p ∧ (p→q) \leftrightarrow p ∧ (¬p ∨ q) \leftrightarrow (p ∧ ¬p) ∨ (p ∧ q) \leftrightarrow \text{false} ∨ (p ∧ q) \leftrightarrow p ∧ q$

Comment: I don't think this answer will help the OP to solve  the next problem he will encounter. And why doyou add a link to Wolframalpha?

Comment: I think this is exactly the step, where our friend sciuni chalaka got stuck. The link to wolframalpha provides a quick method for verification